# Stars and Bars with odd constraints.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given $n$ indistinguishable items, 7 people have at least 23 of those indistinguishable items. In how many ways can an 8th person take exactly 23 of those items from the 7 people such that there are at least 3 people from whom the 8th person takes 6 or more items.

I've started of with the fact that there are $\binom{n-155}{n-161}$ arrangements in which the 7 original people each have at least 23 indistinguishable items. From here I'm having difficulties implementing the other parts of the question. I'm unsure of how to explicitly make 3 specific people give up at least 6 items, because if I just subtract 23 from $n-155$ and distribute it among the 7 original people that covers arrangements where 1 person might give all their items to the 8th person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably each of the $7$ people have $23$ items, so you do not have to worry about it the initial distribution.

Note that $6 \times 3 \lt 23 \lt 6 \times 4$ so the eighth person does not take $6$ or more items from a fourth person

So choose $3$ from the $7$ people in ${7 \choose 3}$ possible ways and take exactly $6$ items from each

That leaves $23-18=5$ items, so take these from the $7$ people in ${11 \choose 5}$ possible ways

So the answer is ${7 \choose 3}{11 \choose 5}$